# Low Level Programming in C#

Tags: .net, c, c#-4.0

I am new to C# .NET. I am migrating from C, C++ to C#.

C# is similar to C but I have some problems to work with it. I think it is possible to do low level programming in C# like C but I did not find any comprehensive way to do low level programming like C.

The Question is how can I do low level programming in C#.

Comment: And the comment is: can you be much more specific about what you mean by 'low-level programming' ?  As your question stands it is likely to attract votes to close.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I voted to close, **and** I posted an answer, how's that for schizofrenic

Comment: "C# is similar to C" - I think its more accurate to say "C# shares some syntax with C" The similarities don't go all that much further

Comment: @Foo42: And even that is more than somewhat debatable.

Comment: IMO question is valid. Saying he works in C and wants "low level" I'd assume he wants assembler code (_asm in C). If that's the question answer is yes, you can do that but even assembly code will be converted to IL.

Comment: Thanks All to Reply. My quiestion was about low level programming like memory management where I can manage all memory resorces on my own and GC does not take place and also hardware can be managed.

Comment: @UzairAnwaar: not gonna happen. Only when you call into native libraries. C++/CLI might be a good match for you. (Frankly, I'm a C++ adept, but the idea that GC is evil isn't accurate. C++ has more power, but GC is not necessarily bad for performance.)

Comment: There has been at least [one OS that is written in C#](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Singularity-A-research-OS-written-in-C), but it depends on how *you're* defining "low level"

Answer (score 7):

Don't know whether this counts as lowlevel programming: treat string as `char*`, pointer arithmetic, hex formatted console output, yay!

Add in a little bit of P/Invoke and call your own native C dlls?

```
using System;
class MainClass 
{
    unsafe public static void Main (string[] args) 
    {
        fixed (char* r = "helloworld".ToCharArray()) 
        {
            char* p = r;
            while (*p != 0)
                Console.WriteLine("{0:X}", (int) *p++);
        }
    }       
}
```

Compile with /unsafe flag, output:

```
68
65 
6C
6C
6F
77
6F
72
6C
64
```